# I can't set State in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, constructor, setstate

In this project I want to set the state of the userType using the data that I retrieved from the firebase database. fetching from the firebase is working correctly but I cant set the state of userType from there

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Image } from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state=({
      userId:firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
      userType:'f'
    })
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.readUserData();
  };
  readUserData=()=> {
    userstype= 'users/'+ this.state.userId + '/userType'

    firebase.database().ref(userstype).on('value', function (snapshot) {
      this.state=({userType:snapshot.val()})
    });

      alert(this.state.userType)
    }


  render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>Taams</Text>
        <Text style={styles.edition}>Developer's Edition</Text>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>Home</Text>
        <Text>Alpha 0.0.0.1</Text>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the state, please try to do as following instead of `this.state=({userType:snapshot.val()})`:
`this.setState({ userType:snapshot.val() });`

Comment: i fixed it. now it working fine readUserData=()=> { userstype= 'users/'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/userType' firebase.database().ref(userstype).once('value').then(snapshot => { this.state=({ uType: snapshot.val() }) })

Answer (score 0):

Only use `this.state ={}` in the constructor.  Everywhere else it should be.

```
this.setState({})
```

so change

```
    firebase.database().ref(userstype).on('value', function (snapshot) {
  this.state=({userType:snapshot.val()})
});
```

to

```
    firebase.database().ref(userstype).on('value', function (snapshot) {
  this.setState({userType:snapshot.val()})
});
```

Comment: getting an Error undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.setState({userType:snapshot.val()})

Comment: Okay.  My next step would be to try & make sure that the snapshot value is available to setState by wrapping setState in a condition..

`    firebase.database().ref(userstype).on('value', function (snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.val()) {
      this.setState({userType:snapshot.val()})
       }
    });`

Comment: And you may want to edit your question to reflect the answer given by @nika95 and myself.  It is definitely the right way to set state.

Comment: With the correct version of setState?  Next I'd console.log(snapshot.val()) above setState make sure the snapshot.val() is available.

Comment: When i set an alert(snapshot.val()) . it is giving the correct output. But it is not setting the state

Comment: i fixed it. now it working fine readUserData=()=> { userstype= 'users/'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/userType' firebase.database().ref(userstype).once('value').then(snapshot => { this.state=({ uType: snapshot.val() }) })

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase.database().ref(userstype).on('value', (snapshot) => {
  this.setState({userType: snapshot.val()})
});
```

This might be a context issue. Without binding the anonymous function, you'll lose the original context. Try using an ES6's arrow function and this.setState({})

Comment: i fixed it. now it working fine           
          readUserData=()=> {
              userstype= 'users/'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/userType'

              firebase.database().ref(userstype).once('value').then(snapshot => {
                  this.state=({ uType: snapshot.val() })
              })